# All wordpress site went white blank screen

Tags: html

NEW: Hi, so the host supporters suggest that automatic update in wordpress might cause this and they provide temporary downgrade php version by code in .htaccess to test and it works?.
what I don't understand is how come more than 5 differents site with absolutely different wordpress core version, different theme, different plugins, like not thing same that automatic update something at the same time and all went blank?
and how does downgrade php version has something to do with confliction betweet (wordpress, theme, plugins update).
Please let me know if you think what might be happening. Thank you very much.

we have a server with a lot of wordpress sites that is running fine. Suddendly, most of the wordpress sites went white blank screen while hardly being changed anything (it means not because of theme or plugin or functions.php). But something might happen to the server that cause this to all wordpress sites? Please help me if anyone has experienced this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, backup your site before you do anything.

This is what I do when encounter such kind of problem:

1.Turn WP_DEBUG as true in your wp-config.php
2.Using default theme to see if the site is ok or not.
3.Deactivate all plugin to see if the site is ok or not.
4.Activate the plugins one by one to see if the site is ok or not.

Comment: when I deactive current theme then I can access to admin dashboard. but then when I try to active any theme its happening again. It is like all the theme is missing to all my wordpress sites?

Comment: Is there any error when you enable WP_DEUG?

Comment: Hi ucheng ! it does not show anything but I got alot of update please see my edit if you have time, thank you very much

Comment: If it does not show anything on the screen, please look into the server error log. There should be something wrong there.  I don't think the PHP version is the root cause, or could you duplicate your site and run on other server or your localhost computer?

Comment: I just duplicate 1 one of it to my localhost and it has the same error, only can access the admin when rename all theme. so something happened cause all the themes error but when downgrade php to 5.6 then it work like normal?